# GTag event for Sign Up with reference to Ad (Utm Variables?)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I created a Facebook ad with a link to a page on my website:

```
https://www.example.net/signup?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=launch
```

With the UTM variables I can track which campaigns the user came from.

I also need to know how many users really signed up so I am trying to use [GTag](http://gtag('event',%20%3Caction%3E,%20%7B%20%20%20'event_category':%20%3Ccategory%3E,%20%20%20'event_label':%20%3Clabel%3E,%20%20%20'value':%20%3Cvalue%3E%20%7D);) to create an event:

```
gtag('event', 'sign_up', {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

How to relate this event with the Facebook campaign defined in the UTM variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user lands on the website from that link with the UTM parameters and completes the desired action (sign_up), Google Analytics will be able to understand for itself if that action is associated with that campaign.

If you set a **goal** in the view so that it activates when an event has action `sign_up`, you will conveniently see in the channel report the number of goals associated with that specific *source / medium*.